# If f is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and if for each $n=0,1,2,3,...$. Prove that $f=0$ on $[0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

If f is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and if for each $n=0,1,2,3,...$

$$ \int_0^1 f(t)t^n dt=0$$

Then prove that $f=0$ on  $[0,1]$.

Here I don't want the proof. I have one proof. But I have tried one by myself. Please check it.

By Weirstrass Approximation test, I have ${P_n}$ a sequence of polynomials which will converge to $f$. Say, $P_n= a_n+b_nx+c_nx^2+......$.

Now $$ \int_0^1 f(t)t^n dt=0\Rightarrow \int_0^1 (\lim_{n\to \infty}P_n(t))t^n dt=0\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 P_n(t)t^n dt=0[As P_n is continuous]\Rightarrow \frac{a_n}{m+1}+\frac{b_n}{m+2}+\frac{c_n}{m+3}+......=0 \forall m \in \Bbb N\Rightarrow a_n \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$.

Hence, $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}P_n(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$.

Now my request is please check it & mention if there is any ambiguity or doubts in the answer. No need to give any other answer. You may clarify & solve the doubts in my answer writting your answer & tell me how to modify it. Otherwise please mention in the comment that it is ok.

Comment: You get $\frac{a_n}{m+1} + \frac{b_n}{m+2} + \cdots \to 0$ for any $m$. This doesn't imply $a_n \to 0$. You may instead condsider  $\int_0^1 f(t)P_n(t)dt$

Comment: Yeah I know I can use the second integral. Actually that is the method I have mentioned. But why this doesn't imply $a_n\to 0$??

Comment: It's just not clear to me why it should. Maybe you can add more details?

Comment: Ok what I was thinking to use some kind of linear independency concept & cancel out other term to show $a_n=0$,$b_n=0$,.... 
Anyway if you have a doubt you can give me a reason. Not a intution. Because I have posted it to check, where and why I am wrong.